# PyQt move vertical scrollbar location in QGraphicsView

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, scrollbar

I have a QGraphicsView in a QTabWidget with its tabs on the left. I want to move the location of the vertical scrollbar of my QGraphicsView to the left side, directly underneath the tabs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found I can do this by creating separate `QTabBar` and `QScrollBar` widgets that are attached to a `QTabWidget` and `QAbstractScrollArea` (I'm using a `QListWidget` now but I'm sure it'll work for `QGraphicsView` too) and then putting those widgets in a `QVBoxLayout`, and then putting the `QVBoxLayout` next to the `QTabWidget`/`QAbstractScrollArea` via a `QHBoxLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [setting the layout direction](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#layoutDirection-prop) on the graphics-view:

```
    self.view.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
```